# Getting "NoSuchElementException: No line found" in NetBeans, but not in DrJava/command line?

Tags: java, netbeans

I'm new to Java & NetBeans and haven't found a question exactly like the current issue I'm having.

I have this basic code that's intended to print the first line of an existing text file:

```
14    File test = new File("C:\\Users\\Computer\\Desktop\\testfile.txt");
15    Scanner read = new Scanner(test);
16    
17    String firstline = read.nextLine();
18    System.out.println(firstline);
19  
20    read.close();
```

For some reason, the same code runs fine in Dr Java and the Windows command line, but in NetBeans, I keep getting this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1585)
at testfile.Testfile.main(Testfile.java:18)
```

Why? One thing I've found that seems to solve the problem is replacing "File" with "FileReader", but I'm not sure why that works.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, you should check if your scanner has some data. Here's an example:

```
File test = new File("D:\\testfile.txt");
Scanner read = new Scanner(test);

String line;
while (read.hasNextLine()) {
    line = read.nextLine();
    // your logic
    System.out.println(line);
}
read.close();
```

Secondly, there are 2 behaviours you should expect from your code when you don't check "read.hasNextLine()" (or read.hasNext or whatever else read.hasXxx method):
1- java.util.NoSuchElementException when your file is **empty**.
2- you will get the first line printed.
-> I tested NetBeans 7.3 RC1 with Java7u13 and it works as it should.

Here you can find more info about I/O and Scanner: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html

Here's the new Java 7 way of using try-with-resources, which automatically creates and closes the Scanner for you. (You can get this with all Objects that implement interface Closeable)

```
File test = new File("D:\\testfile.txt");
try (Scanner read = new Scanner(test)) {
    String line;
    while (read.hasNextLine()) {
    line = read.nextLine();
    // your logic
    System.out.println(line);
    }
}
```

Comment: This was very helpful, but my program is still behaving (in NetBeans) like the file has no lines. The text file is not empty; it has a bunch of sentences in it. I'm quite baffled. I've tried moving the file around, using the above suggested code, etc. Running the program through the command line prints the contents of the same text file without any issues. Maybe there is some misconfigured setting in NetBeans that I'm too much of a newbie to catch? I have no idea. Thanks for the response!

Comment: Then go with a basic solution: remove all Java from your machine, remove NetBeans, then install the latest of both and see if you still get this.
As I said in my previous post, latest NetBeans and Java work flawlessly in this situation.
If this doesn't do it, then it's something wrong with your machine.
Hmm...question: do you have more versions of Java installed? Sometimes this causes strange behaviors.